# EJB 2.1 to EJB 3.1 Migration - Session EJB with name not found

Tags: java, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

> I am migrating Ejb 2.1 to Ejb 3.1. I changed Java Version from 1.6 to 1.8, and Ejb Version from 2.1 to 3.1. Once I made the changes, I am getting problems in the **ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml** and **ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml** files.
> I am getting these messages:
>
> **1: Session EJB with name 'abcEJB' not found**
> **2: Resource reference with name 'ResourceRef_xyz' not found for this EJB or interceptor**
>
> Am I missing anything?

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have migrated from EJB 2.1 to EJB 3.1 couple of years back and I recall facing the same issues and error you are facing.

Although I don't remember the exact action that fixed the issue nor other issues I faced along the way, but I will tell you what I did to fix ALL issues, including this one.

*Note*: It's not an easy task to migrate, but following these next steps as described will save you lots of hassle later on.

1. Annotate session beans and interfaces with proper annotations:
   In my case I had remote interfaces for EJB 2.1 beans. Since I did not need an actual remote interface in my application, I switched them into local interfaces.
2. Empty ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml and ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml
   [image]
3. Change clients to lookup either using DI, JNDI name. In my case I used JNDI lookup.

Now the code should look like this:

**Session Bean interface:**

```
@Local
public interface MySessionInterface {
    // TODO :: declare business methods
}
```

**Session bean implementation:**

```
@stateless
public interface MySessionBeanImpl implements MySessionInterface {
    // TODO :: implement business methods
}
```

**Service Locator to lookup EJBs using JNDI:**

```
public class ServiceLocator {
    public final <T> T getLocalSession(Class<T> _class) throws NamingException {
        return (T) new InitialContext().lookup("ejblocal:" + _class.getName());
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
public class SessionClient {
     public void performOperation() {
         try {
            MySessionInterface session = ServiceLocator.getLocalSession(MySessionInterface.class);
            // TODO :: perform business logic here
        } catch (NamingException e) {
             // TODO :: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Of course service locator can have the following improvements but I removed them for brevity:

- Cache the result instead of looking it up everytime from the JNDI
- Catch the checked exception NamingException and throw your own runtime exception

Hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

In both the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml and ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xml files, the `<session>` element must contain the name of the EJB that it applies to. That name must match the name of an EJB defined in the corresponding ejb-jar.xml file, specifically the `<ejb-name>` element, or the name of the EJB identified by either the @Stateless, @Stateful, or @Singleton annotation.  When using annotations, the name refers to either the name attribute of the annotation, or the simple class name.

Similarly, the `<resource-ref>` element must contain the name of the resource references that it applies to. In ejb-jar.xml, this would be the `<res-ref-name>` element. If the resource reference is defined via annotations, then the name element of the @Resource annotation, or the default name if not specified.